# Compiling HTML in Angular JS Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-directive

I am trying to build the following directive for a simple modal window who's usage would be as follows:

```
<modal content="<div class='error-text'>this is the content</div>"></modal>
```

Which should generate the following markup:

```
<div class="modal-wrap fade-hide fade-show" ng-show="showModal" ng-click="showModal=false">
    <div class="modal-info clearfix" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">

        <div class='error-text'>this is the content</div>

        <button class="btn form-control" ng-click="showModal=false">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my directive so far:

```
.directive('modal', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.content = attrs.content;
        },
        template: '<div class="modal-wrap fade-hide fade-show" ng-show="showModal" ng-click="showModal=false"><div class="modal-info clearfix" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">{{content}}<button class="btn form-control" ng-click="showModal=false">OK</button></div></div>',
    };
})
```

**The problem I am having is that the {{content}} is not being compiled. It is being rendered as literal html.**

And my modal window looks like this:
[image]

How do I configure my directive such that the `content` attribute is compiled as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

> In this sample i used bootstrap for our modal.
>
> **Remember:**  in the directive you can use **scope** instead **Attr** it's much better.
>
> for binding Html in your directive or everywhere use **ng-bind-html** as this sample

**index.html**

```
<modal content="<div class='alert alert-danger'>this is the content</div>"></modal>
```

**modal.html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" ng-bind-html="content | trust">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**filter**

> This filter helps you to bind html as trust codes, we use it in the **modal.html** on **ng-bind-html** attribute.

```
app.filter("trust", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: "modal.html",
        scope: {
            content: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    };
});
```